# GCM: onMessage() from GCMIntentService is never called

Tags: android

I am implementing `GCM (Google Cloud Messaging- PUSH Notifications)` in my application. I have followed all the steps given in GCM tutorial from developer.android.com

My application's build target is pointing to `Goolge API 8 (Android 2.2 version)`.

I am able to get the register ID from GCM successfully, and I am passing this ID to my application server. So the registration step is performed successfully.

Now when my application server sends a PUSH message to my device, the server gets the message as `SUCCESS=1 FAILURE=0, etc.`, i.e. Server is sending message successfully, but my device never receives the message.

After searching alot about this, I came to know that GCM pushes messages on port number 5228, 5229 or 5230.

Initially, my device and laptop was restricted for some websites, but then I was granted all the permissions to access all websites, so I guess these port numbers are open for my device.

So my question is: **I never receive any PUSH message from GCM. My onMessage() from GCMIntenService class is never called. What could be the reason?**

Please see my following code and guide me accordingly:

I have declared following in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="packageName" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ReceiveBroadcast"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GCMIntentService"
            />


/**
 * @author Shrikant.
 * 
 */
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    /**
     * The Sender ID used for GCM.
     */
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "myProjectID";

    /**
     * This field is used to call Web-Service for GCM.
     */
    SendUserCredentialsGCM sendUserCredentialsGCM = null;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
        sendUserCredentialsGCM = new SendUserCredentialsGCM();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        sendUserCredentialsGCM.sendRegistrationID(registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
        sendUserCredentialsGCM
                .unregisterFromGCM(LoginActivity.API_OR_BROWSER_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("GCM MESSAGE", "Message Recieved!!!");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if (message == null) {
            Log.e("NULL MESSAGE", "Message Not Recieved!!!");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "new message= " + message);
            sendGCMIntent(context, message);
        }
    }

    private void sendGCMIntent(Context context, String message) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("gcm", message);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        Toast.makeText(context, "PUSH Notification failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably better asked on SO, I've voted to migrate it.  Good indication of which site to ask your question on is if you are in front of your IDE it should probably be asked on SO.  If you are in front of a white board it belongs here.

Comment: Hello everyone, I am still stuck on this issue, now I have not changed code much but I receive the PUSH messages sometime, but not every time. Its very unreliable. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. I don't understand, why this is happening. Please guide me if possible.

Comment: Shrikant I am also facing the same issue?Can u help me to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed package name you should override getGCMIntentServiceClassName() method in GCMBroadcastReceiver class child. Example [here](http://dexxtr.com/post/28188228252/rename-or-change-package-of-gcmintentservice-class).

Comment: The GCMIntentService is present in my application package only. So this solution will not help. I tried your method as well, but could not receive message. I am still stuck on same issue. If you know some other way, please tell me. Thanks anyways.